# Configuration Persistance Design

Tags: mysql, database-design, best-practices

We have a well designed and normalized DB, but, there is a requisit that could cloud this design.
This image shows the design of part of the DB.
[image: Part of our DB design]
The main functionality of our application is to create some stats of the quantity of notifications each user recieves. So we query the DB by groups of users (e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Notifications INNER JOIN Users ON User.UserID = Notifications.UserID WHERE User.att = ...`).

The requisit that is causing me troubles is that our application allows a user (which is different of any user stored in the table `Users`, since this is a monitoring application) to customize some configuration parameters, such as miliseconds to wait before looking again in the DB in order to obtain some data for charts, which number of notifications makes a user selectable (e.g. if the user has more than *X* notifications then *it should be displayed in the chart*) etc.

This configuration must be persistant, we do not want to make the user set the parameters each time he opens the application.

The problem I see is, how do I make the configuration persistant without clouding the design. Because, if you set, lets say, the *X* number of notifications needed, you could see that as an attribute of `Notifications`, but is kind of an *Entity attribute*. Since, is (conceptually) an attribute of `Notifications` but what we store there are notifications, which are oblivious of configuration attributes.

Moreover, we have more entities, with exactly the same problem. An entity that stores certain kind of data, and from the application you can configure in which ways this data is going to be treated. And that configuration must be persistant.

Therefore, my question is, what is the appropiate way to represent this configuration persistance? Should it be represented in the DB or in other file? I think that it should be stored in the DB, but maybe I am being stubborn...

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do.  Can you expand with some draft tables, or a more concrete example?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I edited the question, I think is much more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on how many parameters you have, and whether this list is expected to be largely static or if it's likely to change or expand.

I'm still a little fuzzy on exactly what you're doing, so I'm going to answer a slightly different question.  Let's say you're writing a query engine, searching for users that meet different requirements, and you want to store a set of predicates so it can be reused.  In a simple world, your table might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Searches
    (
    ID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CreatedBy   INT NOT NULL,  -- Prob also CreatedDate, LastModified, etc.
    FirstName   VARCHAR(100),
    LastName    VARCHAR(100),
    Sex CHAR(1),
    EMailAddress    VARCHAR(100),
    Country INT
    )
```

Some day you'll need to add a `Region` field when you start storing more precise geographic data.  Then you'll add `PhoneNumber`, and then `BloodType`, and then... eventually, you'll need something more flexible.  You need a table for searches and a table to store key-value pairs for each search:

```
CREATE TABLE Searches
    (
    ID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CreatedBy   INT NOT NULL
    )
CREATE TABLE SearchTerms
    (
    ID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SearchID    INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Searches (ID),
    FieldName   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Value   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (SearchID, FieldName)
    )
```

The `UNIQUE` constraint may not be appropriate.  For example, it may be appropriate to have a search with Terms { FieldName = "FirstName", Value = "Bo%" } and { FieldName = "FirstName", Value = "ob%" }.

This more flexible approach loses type checking; searching for "NumArms = 2" now requires storing "2" in a `VARCHAR` field.  It also implies using dynamic SQL to construct your searches.

Comment: Ok, now imagine that instead of having *n* tuples in `Searches` you only have 1 because you only have an user and allways is going to be 1... then, that's my problem... the config values I have to store have an unique occurrence that would change at user (singular) will.

Comment: You can certainly store just one record in `Searches` per user, though if so you may just want to add search preference fields to the `Users` table.  How is this a problem?

Comment: The problem is that there is just 1 unique user with options. And that user, lets call it now "program" (it is more clear) have no representation yet on the DB. So if it had it would be a relationless table with just one tuple.

Comment: So there will only ever be one program, reporting on the many users?  With just one record in its hypothetical `SearchTerms` table?  Then how you store it hardly matters, since you're talking about just a few bytes anyway.  I must be missing something.

Comment: This is a good practices problem. It is wierd for me to have an table without any relationship with the orders. Since the program has no representation in the DB. It is like if you have your E/R diagram, with entities conected with each other, and then, you have a lonely entity with no relationships and with just one tuple... it is kind of a wierd table and I think it is not a good design.

Comment: Unusual, yes, but if it really has no relationships there's no reason to concoct one.  If it really grinds your gears to store this in the DB, then your application layer could instead write this preference info to a cookie or an app config file.

Comment: @eversor - Jon of All Trades is correct (+1).  Configuration settings belong in a configuration settings table, or outside of the database.  Where you are going wrong is in thinking that the _number of notifications needed_ is an attribute of `Notifications`.  This is, in my opinion, one of the reasons why it is bad to use plural nouns for table names in general.  The `Notifications` table is not the place to put everything about notifications, it is the place to store a set of individual notification records. Your setting is an attribute of the system user, not of notifications.

Comment: @JoelBrown good point about plural nouns!